# how to send string by http post in UTF-8

Tags: android

I try to send string "Привет мир!"

```
String link = POST_URL;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
String xml ="Привет мир";
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", xml));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

And save it by php script:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['file'])){
$fp = fopen("C:\\windows\\temp\\1.xml", "w");
$mytext =$_POST["file"];
$test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); 
fclose($fp);
```

But I get ?????? ????? on my web server, I try reopen file with utf encoding, but it doesn't help. How can I resolve it.

Comment: `UrlEncodedFormEntity` uses [`ISO 8859-1`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) encoding by default which doesn't support russian characters. You can speficy the encoding in the `UrlEncodedFormEntity`'s constructor. `new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The StringEntity's charset to UTF-8. These lines will do the trick:

```
 httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Comment: It's since been deprecated. Use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://someurl.com");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8));
```